# How to check duplication of value not insert in Table?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have one issue in MVC JQuery. please resolve this issue. I really appreciate your help. Let me explain you my concern.

Actually I have a dropdown in which there is some list of items and i am just adding them in the table but i want when i select any item and added in the table and again i select that item and trying to add that in the table i will get the alert that "Already Exist". But i am unable to do this.

Let me share my code with you.

```
    $("#addToList").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($.trim($("#StockID").val()) == "" || $.trim($("#Quantity").val()) == "" || $.trim($("#Price").val()) == "")
        return;

    var productName = $("#StockID option:selected").text();
    var pid = $("#StockID option:selected").val();
    let price = $("#Price").val();
    let quantity = $("#Quantity").val();

    let detailsTableBody = $("#detailsTable tbody");
    var productItem = `<tr>
                            <td pid=${pid}>
                                ${productName}
                            </td>
                            <td><span data-line_qty="${quantity}" data-itemId="0" href="#" class="qtyItem" >${quantity}</span></td>

                            <td>${price}</td>
                            <td>${(parseFloat(price) * parseInt(quantity))}</td>
                           <td><a data-line_total="${(parseFloat(price) * parseInt(quantity, 10))}" data-itemId="0" href="#" class="deleteItem">Remove</a></td>
                        </tr>`;

    detailsTableBody.append(productItem);
    calc_total();
    clearItem();
});
```

Let me share my output[image: click here]

Comment: Where is your logic that is trying to prevent this?

Comment: It's seems you're using some templating library, I cannot tell which one. One way to do this is to add the the items to an array. Before you add a new item to table, check array first. If item exists, show alert. If not add to array then to table.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is not a permanent approach, if you refresh page it will be all gone.

Comment: I have a table from which i am getting values in the dropdown. When i select any item from the dropdown and click on add to list button that item add in the below table. If i again select the same item and click on add button then it will again add. I do not want this. I want i got a alert for this. Please help me its really hard for me. I am a new one in Jquery.

Comment: Please don't spam language tags - only include the language which you have a question about.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using HashTable or set. On selecting the item push into hash table as well and check if the item is already in hash table code then show the alert message.

You can implement hashTable like -

```
var itemsAdded = {};
if(itemsAdded[item]){
  alert('Item is already added !');
} else {
  itemsAdded[item] = item;
}
```